# Blank screen after resuming from suspend state on Ubuntu 16.04 (issue started after installing Nvidia Drivers)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, suspend

I installed ubuntu MATE 16.04.1 (the latest version) and now I am facing a graphics related issue.

Everytime I try to resume the system after closing the lid or manually suspending it, a blank or black screen appears. And due to this I have to shut off the system by holding power button in order to reboot it.

This started happening after installing Nvidia drivers.

I tried upgrading the kernel to 4.4.8 as suggested by few posts on this portal related to this issue, but it did not work.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks a Lot for your Time

Answer (score 1):

Found many posts but could not find any solution as of now.

Answering my own question, I am currently using a work around using bumblebee. This might be useful to those who are still facing this issue.

1. Open nvidia-settings (open terminal and type nvidia-settings)
2. Go to Prime Profiles tab and switch to Intel graphics
3. Reboot the system
4. Follow this link to install and setup bumblebee [link](https://lenovolinux.blogspot.si/2016/05/bumblebee-on-lenovo-t440p-nvidia-gt.html)
5. Whenever you need to run a program which requires GPU hardware, include "primusrun" ahead of the command (eg., primusrun ./deviceQuery)

This brings another issue for me, whenever I suspend my system and after resuming bumblebee can not locate GPU resources.
Currently trying to solve this one.