# 16.04 on Lenovo, screen doesn't come on after suspend

Tags: suspend

A couple days ago I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 on a Lenovo Z50-75.  When I close the lid, it suspends and powers down correctly; when I open the lid, I can hear the hard disk spin up, but the screen never comes back on, and I wind up having to power it off.

[Won't come back from suspend 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760381/wont-come-back-from-suspend-16-04-lts) and [Xubuntu 16.04.1 won't wake up correctly after opening lid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835598/xubuntu-16-04-1-wont-wake-up-correctly-after-opening-lid) seemed similar, so I followed the instructions [on Linux Daddy here](http://linuxdaddy.com/blog/install-kernel-4-4-on-ubuntu/) and am now running a 4.4.25 kernel, but that didn't help.

Manually running `sudo pm-suspend --quirk-dpms-on` has the same effect: the machine powers down; pressing space or whatever causes it to spin back up, but the screen never turns back on.

I see other answers talk about editing your `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`; I haven't changed anything in there (as my problem is on resume, not suspend).  Everything in that file is commented out.

I see [My Lenovo Z40 can't recover from sleep/suspend mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837692/my-lenovo-z40-cant-recover-from-sleep-suspend-mode) is about 16.04 on a Lenovo Z40 (similar I think to my Z50), and the one answer there mentions the Nvidia driver.  However, the `lshw` and `lspci` commands used [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus) to figure out your NVIDIA card model don't say anything about an NVIDIA card; they just say AMD Radeon.

[This page on help.ubuntu.com](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Screen_Blanks.2FMonitor_Turns_Off) talks about editing your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, but I don't have one of those, and there's no "Screen" section in anything under `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.

[Blank screen after resuming from suspend state on Ubuntu 16.04 (issue started after installing Nvidia Drivers)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809094/blank-screen-after-resuming-from-suspend-state-on-ubuntu-16-04-issue-started-af) has instructions on working around it by installing bumblebee; I did that ("sort of"--see below), but there was a warning during the installation:

```
No Nvidia card found. If you really have an Optimus system,
try selecting the Optimus setup in BIOS and run:
sudo dpkg-reconfigure bumblebee-nvidia
```

I say I "sort of" did that, because step 1 & 2 was switching to Intel graphics in nvidia-settings, and... I had some problem with my nvidia-settings installation (starting it up, it complained that the registry key file should've been installed along with the driver, and to see the README; there was no README, either).  And bumblebee isn't quite working (the Bumblebee daemon isn't starting automatically?), but I don't think I care.  In any case, this didn't fix it, although maybe that's because I didn't do it correctly.

The only real progress I've made is adding the `/etc/pm/sleep.d/01_switchvt` script suggested in the answer to [Unable to resume after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/436133/unable-to-resume-after-suspend).  After adding that, manually running `pm-suspend`, and then hitting the spacebar, the machine starts back up properly; but closing the lid, waiting, & reopening it (and flailing on the keyboard, etc.) still doesn't turn the screen back on.  That seems to be a step in the right direction, at least...  So, seeing on [this thread on Fedora Forums](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=299457) that `systemd` might be doing the sleep, I put something similar in my `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`, and I can see (from writing to a log file) that it's successfully calling `chvt` during suspend & resume, but that didn't fix it.

Any idea how I can get suspend/resume to work again?

Comment: OK, people, it's now 2017, and I can't close the lid on my Linux laptop.  You know what this reminds me of?  1997!

Answer (score 0):

I work with two Lenovo laptops, and each required a different configuration in order to get suspend/resume to work under Ubuntu 16.10.

- With the Lenovo u300s, the solution was to add `pci=nomsi` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` string
- While with the Lenovo IdeaPad Z510, the solution was to add `i915.enable_psr=0`

Here are the specific details of what I had to do to configure each:

- Create an appropriately-sized swap file (I typically set for ~1.1x of total size, so 18GB for a 16GB)
- In etc/default/grub, configure `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to include the `resume` parameter, passing the UUID of the swap partition in question (e.g., `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=453f0121-505d-42d3-8dad-87f913e67ddc"`)
- Add to that same `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line either of the above solutions (either the `pci=nomsi` or `i915.enable_psr=0` parameter), e.g., `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=453f0121-505d-42d3-8dad-87f913e67ddc`pci=nomsi`"`
- Run `sudo update-grub`
- Edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` to set `HandleLidSwitch=hibernate` (or similar)
- Run `sudo service systemd-logind restart`

While I'm not a big fan of just plugging in random grub parameters without fully understanding the implications of what each parameter does, it may help you in troubleshooting/limiting the scope of your suspend issues on your Lenovo laptop.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hey, thank you for replying, but neither of those grub options worked for me.  (One thing you suggested that I _didn't_ do was the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` change, because I _think_ I want it to be `suspend` instead of `hibernate`, and the logind.conf man page says that's its default value.)